# Outlook Add-in not rendering in 2016

Tags: outlook, manifest, outlook-addin, outlook-web-app, outlook-2016

I am creating an Outlook Add-in, which works perfectly fine in Outlook 2013. In Outlook 2016, however, nothing shows up. The ribbon items are completely gone. In 2013, there are three ribbon buttons that show up, that do not in 2016.

Any ideas what might be wrong in the manifest file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<OfficeApp
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/appforoffice/1.1"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:bt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/officeappbasictypes/1.0"
    xmlns:mailappor="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides"
    xsi:type="MailApp">
  <Id>3a2be270-ea2f-407c-97f1-138f67352cb4</Id>
  <Version>1.1.9</Version>
  <ProviderName>--REMOVED--</ProviderName>
  <DefaultLocale>en-US</DefaultLocale>
  <DisplayName DefaultValue="--REMOVED-- for PS"/>
  <Description DefaultValue="[Outlook Add-in description]"/>
  <IconUrl DefaultValue="https://localhost/--REMOVED--PS/outlook/images/icon-32.png"/>
  <HighResolutionIconUrl DefaultValue="https://localhost/--REMOVED--PS/outlook/images/icon-80.png"/>
  <SupportUrl DefaultValue="https://help.--REMOVED--.com/Product/--REMOVED--PS/"/>
  <Hosts>
    <Host Name="Mailbox"/>
  </Hosts>
  <Requirements>
    <Sets>
      <Set Name="MailBox" MinVersion="1.1"/>
    </Sets>
  </Requirements>
  <FormSettings>
    <Form xsi:type="ItemRead">
      <DesktopSettings>
        <SourceLocation DefaultValue="https://localhost/--REMOVED--PS/outlook/appread/home/home.html"/>
        <RequestedHeight>250</RequestedHeight>
      </DesktopSettings>
    </Form>
  </FormSettings>
  <Permissions>ReadItem</Permissions>
  <Rule xsi:type="RuleCollection" Mode="Or">
    <Rule xsi:type="ItemIs" ItemType="Message" FormType="Read"/>
  </Rule>
  <DisableEntityHighlighting>false</DisableEntityHighlighting>
  <VersionOverrides xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides" xsi:type="VersionOverridesV1_0">
    <Hosts>
      <Host xsi:type="MailHost">
        <DesktopFormFactor>
          <FunctionFile resid="funcFile"/>

          <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="MessageReadCommandSurface">
            <OfficeTab id="TabDefault">
              <Group id="msgReadCmdGroup">
                <Label resid="groupLabel"/>
                <Control xsi:type="Button" id="msgReadPaneButton">
                  <Label resid="msgReadPaneButtonLabel"/>
                  <Supertip>
                    <Title resid="msgReadPaneButtonTitle"/>
                    <Description resid="msgReadPaneButtonDesc"/>
                  </Supertip>
                  <Icon>
                    <bt:Image size="16" resid="--REMOVED---16"/>
                    <bt:Image size="32" resid="--REMOVED---32"/>
                    <bt:Image size="80" resid="--REMOVED---80"/>
                  </Icon>
                  <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
                    <SourceLocation resid="readPaneUrl"/>
                  </Action>
                </Control>
                <Control xsi:type="Menu" id="msgCreateMenu">
                  <Label resid="menuCreateLabel"/>
                  <Supertip>
                    <Title resid="menuCreateTitle"/>
                    <Description resid="menuCreateDescription"/>
                  </Supertip>
                  <Icon>
                    <bt:Image size="16" resid="new-16"/>
                    <bt:Image size="32" resid="new-32"/>
                    <bt:Image size="80" resid="new-80"/>
                  </Icon>
                  <Items>
                    <Item id="msgCreateContact">
                      <Label resid="createContactLabel"/>
                      <Supertip>
                        <Title resid="createContactTitle"/>
                        <Description resid="createContactDesc"/>
                      </Supertip>
                      <Icon>
                        <bt:Image size="16" resid="contact-16"/>
                        <bt:Image size="32" resid="contact-32"/>
                        <bt:Image size="80" resid="contact-80"/>
                      </Icon>
                      <Action xsi:type="ExecuteFunction">
                        <FunctionName>createContact</FunctionName>
                      </Action>
                    </Item>
                    <Item id="msgCreateFirm">
                      <Label resid="createFirmLabel"/>
                      <Supertip>
                        <Title resid="createFirmTitle"/>
                        <Description resid="createFirmDesc"/>
                      </Supertip>
                      <Icon>
                        <bt:Image size="16" resid="firm-16"/>
                        <bt:Image size="32" resid="firm-32"/>
                        <bt:Image size="80" resid="firm-80"/>
                      </Icon>
                      <Action xsi:type="ExecuteFunction">
                        <FunctionName>createFirm</FunctionName>
                      </Action>
                    </Item>
                    <Item id="msgCreateOpportunity">
                      <Label resid="createOpportunityLabel"/>
                      <Supertip>
                        <Title resid="createOpportunityTitle"/>
                        <Description resid="createOpportunityDesc"/>
                      </Supertip>
                      <Icon>
                        <bt:Image size="16" resid="opportunity-16"/>
                        <bt:Image size="32" resid="opportunity-32"/>
                        <bt:Image size="80" resid="opportunity-80"/>
                      </Icon>
                      <Action xsi:type="ExecuteFunction">
                        <FunctionName>createOpportunity</FunctionName>
                      </Action>
                    </Item>
                    <Item id="msgCreateActivity">
                      <Label resid="createActivityLabel"/>
                      <Supertip>
                        <Title resid="createActivityTitle"/>
                        <Description resid="createActivityDesc"/>
                      </Supertip>
                      <Icon>
                        <bt:Image size="16" resid="activity-16"/>
                        <bt:Image size="32" resid="activity-32"/>
                        <bt:Image size="80" resid="activity-80"/>
                      </Icon>
                      <Action xsi:type="ExecuteFunction">
                        <FunctionName>createActivity</FunctionName>
                      </Action>
                    </Item>
                  </Items>
                </Control>
                <Control xsi:type="Menu" id="msgSetttingHelpMenu">
                  <Label resid="menuSettingsHelpLabel"/>
                  <Supertip>
                    <Title resid="menuSettingsHelpTitle"/>
                    <Description resid="menuSettingsHelpDescription"/>
                  </Supertip>
                  <Icon>
                    <bt:Image size="16" resid="settings-16"/>
                    <bt:Image size="32" resid="settings-32"/>
                    <bt:Image size="80" resid="settings-80"/>
                  </Icon>
                  <Items>
                    <Item id="msgCheckAccountInformation">
                      <Label resid="checkAccountInformationLabel"/>
                      <Supertip>
                        <Title resid="checkAccountInformationTitle"/>
                        <Description resid="checkAccountInformationDesc"/>
                      </Supertip>
                      <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
                        <SourceLocation resid="settingsPaneUrl"/>
                      </Action>
                    </Item>
                    <Item id="msgCheckHelp">
                      <Label resid="checkHelpLabel"/>
                      <Supertip>
                        <Title resid="checkHelpTitle"/>
                        <Description resid="checkHelpDesc"/>
                      </Supertip>
                      <Action xsi:type="ExecuteFunction">
                        <FunctionName>checkHelp</FunctionName>
                      </Action>
                    </Item>
                  </Items>
                </Control>
              </Group>
            </OfficeTab>
          </ExtensionPoint>

        </DesktopFormFactor>
      </Host>
    </Hosts>
    <Resources>
      <bt:Images>
        <bt:Image id="--REMOVED---16" DefaultValue="https://localhost/--REMOVED--PS/outlook/images/--REMOVED---16.png"/>
        <bt:Image id="--REMOVED---32" DefaultValue="https://localhost/--REMOVED--PS/outlook/images/--REMOVED---32.png"/>
        <bt:Image id="--REMOVED---80" DefaultValue="https://localhost/--REMOVED--PS/outlook/images/--REMOVED---80.png"/>
        <bt:Image id="new-16" DefaultValue="https://localhost/--REMOVED--PS/outlook/images/new-16.png"/>
        <bt:Image id="new-32" DefaultValue="https://localhost/--REMOVED--PS/outlook/images/new-32.png"/>
        <bt:Image id="new-80" DefaultValue="https://localhost/--REMOVED--PS/outlook/images/new-80.png"/>
        <bt:Image id="settings-16" DefaultValue="https://localhost/--REMOVED--PS/outlook/images/settings-16.png"/>
        <bt:Image id="settings-32" DefaultValue="https://localhost/--REMOVED--PS/outlook/images/settings-32.png"/>
        <bt:Image id="settings-80" DefaultValue="https://localhost/--REMOVED--PS/outlook/images/settings-80.png"/>
        <bt:Image id="activity-16" DefaultValue="https://localhost/--REMOVED--PS/outlook/images/activity-16.png"/>
        <bt:Image id="activity-32" DefaultValue="https://localhost/--REMOVED--PS/outlook/images/activity-32.png"/>
        <bt:Image id="activity-80" DefaultValue="https://localhost/--REMOVED--PS/outlook/images/activity-80.png"/>
        <bt:Image id="contact-16" DefaultValue="https://localhost/--REMOVED--PS/outlook/images/contact-16.png"/>
        <bt:Image id="contact-32" DefaultValue="https://localhost/--REMOVED--PS/outlook/images/contact-32.png"/>
        <bt:Image id="contact-80" DefaultValue="https://localhost/--REMOVED--PS/outlook/images/contact-80.png"/>
        <bt:Image id="firm-16" DefaultValue="https://localhost/--REMOVED--PS/outlook/images/firms-16.png"/>
        <bt:Image id="firm-32" DefaultValue="https://localhost/--REMOVED--PS/outlook/images/firms-32.png"/>
        <bt:Image id="firm-80" DefaultValue="https://localhost/--REMOVED--PS/outlook/images/firms-80.png"/>
        <bt:Image id="opportunity-16" DefaultValue="https://localhost/--REMOVED--PS/outlook/images/opportunity-16.png"/>
        <bt:Image id="opportunity-32" DefaultValue="https://localhost/--REMOVED--PS/outlook/images/opportunity-32.png"/>
        <bt:Image id="opportunity-80" DefaultValue="https://localhost/--REMOVED--PS/outlook/images/opportunity-80.png"/>
      </bt:Images>
      <bt:Urls>
        <bt:Url id="funcFile" DefaultValue="https://localhost/--REMOVED--PS/outlook/appread/home/Functions.html"/>
        <bt:Url id="readPaneUrl" DefaultValue="https://localhost/--REMOVED--PS/outlook/appread/home/home.html"/>
        <bt:Url id="settingsPaneUrl" DefaultValue="https://localhost/--REMOVED--PS/outlook/appread/home/home.html?pane=Settings"/>
      </bt:Urls>
      <bt:ShortStrings>
        <bt:String id="groupLabel" DefaultValue="--REMOVED--"/>
        <bt:String id="msgReadPaneButtonLabel" DefaultValue="Open --REMOVED--"/>
        <bt:String id="menuCreateLabel" DefaultValue="Create New"/>
        <bt:String id="menuSettingsHelpLabel" DefaultValue="Settings and Help"/>
        <bt:String id="createContactLabel" DefaultValue="Contact"/>
        <bt:String id="createFirmLabel" DefaultValue="Firm"/>
        <bt:String id="createOpportunityLabel" DefaultValue="Opportunity"/>
        <bt:String id="createActivityLabel" DefaultValue="Activity"/>
        <bt:String id="checkAccountInformationLabel" DefaultValue="Account Information"/>
        <bt:String id="checkHelpLabel" DefaultValue="Help"/>
        <bt:String id="msgReadPaneButtonTitle" DefaultValue="--REMOVED--"/>
        <bt:String id="menuCreateTitle" DefaultValue="Create New"/>
        <bt:String id="createOpportunityTitle" DefaultValue="Create New Opportunity"/>
        <bt:String id="checkHelpTitle" DefaultValue="Help"/>
        <bt:String id="checkAccountInformationTitle" DefaultValue="Account Information"/>
        <bt:String id="createActivityTitle" DefaultValue="Create New Activity"/>
        <bt:String id="createFirmTitle" DefaultValue="Create New Firm"/>
        <bt:String id="menuSettingsHelpTitle" DefaultValue="Settings and Help"/>
        <bt:String id="createContactTitle" DefaultValue="Create New Contact"/>
      </bt:ShortStrings>
      <bt:LongStrings>
        <bt:String id="msgReadPaneButtonDesc" DefaultValue="Opens a task pane showing information about the contacts"/>
        <bt:String id="checkAccountInformationDesc" DefaultValue="Update your account information for --REMOVED-- for Professional Services"/>
        <bt:String id="createContactDesc" DefaultValue="Open --REMOVED-- for Professional Services to create a new Contact"/>
        <bt:String id="createFirmDesc" DefaultValue="Open --REMOVED-- for Professional Services to create a new Firm"/>
        <bt:String id="createOpportunityDesc" DefaultValue="Open --REMOVED-- for Professional Services to create a new Opportunity"/>
        <bt:String id="createActivityDesc" DefaultValue="Open --REMOVED-- for Professional Services to create a new Activity"/>
        <bt:String id="checkHelpDesc" DefaultValue="Open --REMOVED-- for Professional Services to check the help interface"/>
        <bt:String id="menuCreateDescription" DefaultValue="Create a new Contact, Firm, Opportunity or Activity in --REMOVED-- for Professional Services."/>
        <bt:String id="menuSettingsHelpDescription" DefaultValue="Update your account information or access help."/>
      </bt:LongStrings>
    </Resources>
    <VersionOverrides xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides/1.1" xsi:type="VersionOverridesV1_1">
      <Hosts>
        <Host xsi:type="MailHost">
          <DesktopFormFactor>
            <FunctionFile resid="funcFile"/>

            <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="MessageReadCommandSurface">
              <OfficeTab id="TabDefault">
                <Group id="msgReadCmdGroup">
                  <Label resid="groupLabel"/>
                  <Control xsi:type="Button" id="msgReadPaneButton">
                    <Label resid="msgReadPaneButtonLabel"/>
                    <Supertip>
                      <Title resid="msgReadPaneButtonTitle"/>
                      <Description resid="msgReadPaneButtonDesc"/>
                    </Supertip>
                    <Icon>
                      <bt:Image size="16" resid="--REMOVED---16"/>
                      <bt:Image size="32" resid="--REMOVED---32"/>
                      <bt:Image size="80" resid="--REMOVED---80"/>
                    </Icon>
                    <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
                      <SourceLocation resid="readPaneUrl"/>
                      <SupportsPinning>true</SupportsPinning>
                    </Action>
                  </Control>
                  <Control xsi:type="Menu" id="msgCreateMenu">
                    <Label resid="menuCreateLabel"/>
                    <Supertip>
                      <Title resid="menuCreateTitle"/>
                      <Description resid="menuCreateDescription"/>
                    </Supertip>
                    <Icon>
                      <bt:Image size="16" resid="new-16"/>
                      <bt:Image size="32" resid="new-32"/>
                      <bt:Image size="80" resid="new-80"/>
                    </Icon>
                    <Items>
                      <Item id="msgCreateContact">
                        <Label resid="createContactLabel"/>
                        <Supertip>
                          <Title resid="createContactTitle"/>
                          <Description resid="createContactDesc"/>
                        </Supertip>
                        <Icon>
                          <bt:Image size="16" resid="contact-16"/>
                          <bt:Image size="32" resid="contact-32"/>
                          <bt:Image size="80" resid="contact-80"/>
                        </Icon>
                        <Action xsi:type="ExecuteFunction">
                          <FunctionName>createContact</FunctionName>
                        </Action>
                      </Item>
                      <Item id="msgCreateFirm">
                        <Label resid="createFirmLabel"/>
                        <Supertip>
                          <Title resid="createFirmTitle"/>
                          <Description resid="createFirmDesc"/>
                        </Supertip>
                        <Icon>
                          <bt:Image size="16" resid="firm-16"/>
                          <bt:Image size="32" resid="firm-32"/>
                          <bt:Image size="80" resid="firm-80"/>
                        </Icon>
                        <Action xsi:type="ExecuteFunction">
                          <FunctionName>createFirm</FunctionName>
                        </Action>
                      </Item>
                      <Item id="msgCreateOpportunity">
                        <Label resid="createOpportunityLabel"/>
                        <Supertip>
                          <Title resid="createOpportunityTitle"/>
                          <Description resid="createOpportunityDesc"/>
                        </Supertip>
                        <Icon>
                          <bt:Image size="16" resid="opportunity-16"/>
                          <bt:Image size="32" resid="opportunity-32"/>
                          <bt:Image size="80" resid="opportunity-80"/>
                        </Icon>
                        <Action xsi:type="ExecuteFunction">
                          <FunctionName>createOpportunity</FunctionName>
                        </Action>
                      </Item>
                      <Item id="msgCreateActivity">
                        <Label resid="createActivityLabel"/>
                        <Supertip>
                          <Title resid="createActivityTitle"/>
                          <Description resid="createActivityDesc"/>
                        </Supertip>
                        <Icon>
                          <bt:Image size="16" resid="activity-16"/>
                          <bt:Image size="32" resid="activity-32"/>
                          <bt:Image size="80" resid="activity-80"/>
                        </Icon>
                        <Action xsi:type="ExecuteFunction">
                          <FunctionName>createActivity</FunctionName>
                        </Action>
                      </Item>
                    </Items>
                  </Control>
                  <Control xsi:type="Menu" id="msgSetttingHelpMenu">
                    <Label resid="menuSettingsHelpLabel"/>
                    <Supertip>
                      <Title resid="menuSettingsHelpTitle"/>
                      <Description resid="menuSettingsHelpDescription"/>
                    </Supertip>
                    <Icon>
                      <bt:Image size="16" resid="settings-16"/>
                      <bt:Image size="32" resid="settings-32"/>
                      <bt:Image size="80" resid="settings-80"/>
                    </Icon>
                    <Items>
                      <Item id="msgCheckAccountInformation">
                        <Label resid="checkAccountInformationLabel"/>
                        <Supertip>
                          <Title resid="checkAccountInformationTitle"/>
                          <Description resid="checkAccountInformationDesc"/>
                        </Supertip>
                        <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
                          <SourceLocation resid="settingsPaneUrl"/>
                          <SupportsPinning>true</SupportsPinning>
                        </Action>
                      </Item>
                      <Item id="msgCheckHelp">
                        <Label resid="checkHelpLabel"/>
                        <Supertip>
                          <Title resid="checkHelpTitle"/>
                          <Description resid="checkHelpDesc"/>
                        </Supertip>
                        <Action xsi:type="ExecuteFunction">
                          <FunctionName>checkHelp</FunctionName>
                        </Action>
                      </Item>
                    </Items>
                  </Control>
                </Group>
              </OfficeTab>
            </ExtensionPoint>

          </DesktopFormFactor>
        </Host>
      </Hosts>
    </VersionOverrides>
  </VersionOverrides>
</OfficeApp>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the `<Supertip>` tag there are `<Title>` and `<Description>`. The `<Title>` resource must be placed into `<bt:ShortStrings>` parent tag. In the same time the `<Description>` resource must be placed into `<bt:LongStrings>` parent tag.

Documentation on [Office Add-ins XML manifest](https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/overview/add-in-manifests?product=outlook) stated the following:

- **Title**: Required. The text for the supertip. The resid attribute must be set to the value of the id attribute of a String element. The String element is a child element of the ShortStrings element, which is a child element of the Resources element.
- **Description**: Required. The description for the supertip. The resid attribute must be set to the value of the id attribute of a String element. The String element is a child element of the LongStrings element, which is a child element of the Resources element.

To fix your manifest I have moved the following Resource Ids into `<bt:ShortStrings>` ...

```
<bt:ShortStrings>
    <bt:String id="groupLabel" DefaultValue="--REMOVED--"/>
    <bt:String id="msgReadPaneButtonLabel" DefaultValue="Open --REMOVED--"/>
    <bt:String id="menuCreateLabel" DefaultValue="Create New"/>
    <bt:String id="menuSettingsHelpLabel" DefaultValue="Settings and Help"/>
    <bt:String id="createContactLabel" DefaultValue="Contact"/>
    <bt:String id="createFirmLabel" DefaultValue="Firm"/>
    <bt:String id="createOpportunityLabel" DefaultValue="Opportunity"/>
    <bt:String id="createActivityLabel" DefaultValue="Activity"/>
    <bt:String id="checkAccountInformationLabel" DefaultValue="Account Information"/>
    <bt:String id="checkHelpLabel" DefaultValue="Help"/>
    <bt:String id="msgReadPaneButtonTitle" DefaultValue="--REMOVED--"/>
    <bt:String id="menuCreateTitle" DefaultValue="Create New"/>
    <bt:String id="createOpportunityTitle" DefaultValue="Create New Opportunity"/>
    <bt:String id="checkHelpTitle" DefaultValue="Help"/>
    <bt:String id="checkAccountInformationTitle" DefaultValue="Account Information"/>
    <bt:String id="createActivityTitle" DefaultValue="Create New Activity"/>
    <bt:String id="createFirmTitle" DefaultValue="Create New Firm"/>
    <bt:String id="menuSettingsHelpTitle" DefaultValue="Settings and Help"/>
    <bt:String id="createContactTitle" DefaultValue="Create New Contact"/>
  </bt:ShortStrings>
```

**EDIT:**

This is become "remote debugging" instead of QandA, but I already done it anyway. After take a closer look on your manifest and replacing all image entries with my own I realize you are missing entire `<Resources>` section in your `<VersionOverrides>` element. You must have this tag inside [VersionOverrides](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/manifest/versionoverrides?product=outlook) element. As long as I added the section the add-in appeared in Outlook Desktop. Please note, the resource strings in VersionOverrides element will override the same strings in the parent element.

[image]

Comment: I have updated the above with these changes and reinstalled the add-in. The add-in still does not show.

Comment: The Resources element missing was the problem. Thank you.